# Problems with implementing Lucas–Lehmer primality test

Tags: javascript, algorithm, primes

I try to implement the Lucas–Lehmer test (LLT) primality test for Mersenne numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test). It should be polynomial and hence fast. Here is my code:

```
function countPrimeNumberWithDigits(numberOfDigits)
    {
        if(numberOfDigits < 1)
        {return "Please give a valid input!";}

        var shouldBeMoreThanThis = Math.pow(10, numberOfDigits-1), n = 3, M = countMWithIndex(n);
        while(M < shouldBeMoreThanThis)
        {
            n += 2;
            M = countMWithIndex(n);
        }

        console.log(n);

        while(true)
        {
            var S = 4, k = 1;
            M = countMWithIndex(n);

            while(k != n - 1)
            {
                S = (S*S - 2)%M;
                k +=1;
            }

            if(S!=0)
            {n+=2;}
            else
            {break;}
        }

        return "Prime number: " + countMWithIndex(n);
    }

function countMWithIndex(n)
    {return Math.pow(2, n) - 1;}
```

Here is attempt to use the algorithm implemented above:
https://oobarbazanoo.github.io/findPrimeNumberWithSpecifiedQuantumOfDigits/

When I try number of digits which is less than 7 everything is okay, but when I try to ask for prime number with at least 7 digits the program just stumbles and doesn`t give an answer.

Please, help me. What is wrong with my algorithm implementation or what is wrong with my program itself?

Comment: I see prime numbers, quantum digits, etc. I upvote

Comment: AFAIK, javascript will evaluate `-2 % 5` to `-2`. In most algorithms, it should evaluate to `3` (although mathematically both are correct). You might want to do `S = (S*S - 2 + M) % M` to fix this. I don't know if this is the only (potential) issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I run the code on https://repl.it/languages/javascript with this change:

```
S = (S*S - 2 + M)%M;
```

Then it finishes for (seemingly) any number of digits. However, the results seem incorrect: it outputs non-primes with more digits than requested.

The problem is that javascript can evaluate modulo to negative results. For example, `-2 % 5` will be `-2`. This is mathematically correct, but most computer science algorithms require positive values, so `3` in this case.

Adding `M` in that formula will ensure that the result is positive regardless of language quirks.

The problem with incorrect results is likely due to the fact that you do not follow this requirement:

> The Lucas–Lehmer test works as follows. Let Mp = 2**p − 1 be the Mersenne number to test **with p an odd prime**.

The `p` there is the `n` in your code. Nowhere do you ensure that `n` is prime.

Then there is also that javascript's integer type might not be big enough. With `n` larger than `23`, it starts to reach its limits. For example, there is no Mersenne prime with 7 digits. The next is with 10 digits, which is `2**31 - 1`.

You won't be able to find it in (pure) javascript however, because the computation involves squaring `2**31 - 1`, [which exceeds the bounds of javascript's integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, on my 64 bit devices, squaring 2**31 - 1 in JavaScript works correctly.

Comment: @גלעדברקן it doesn't on repl.it. Anyway, what about `2**37-1` and larger? The problem should still be there even if at slightly different values. Sorry, I'm not very familiar with JS, I just found that link on google, which says the max is `2**53-1`.

Comment: But I don`t care whether or nor S becomes less than zero. I just check at the end whether or not it is equal to zero. And as a result it is not a problem for me to have negative results after module operation.

Comment: @Yaroslav you should care, because it causes the infinite loop. The incorrect answer is because of the other problems I mentioned.

Comment: @IVlad, I don`t understand how can it cause an infinite loop. Can you walk me through the part of my code where there may by the infinite loop, please? I check for 'S' to be zero and if it is negative nothing will be different from when it is positive.

Comment: @Yaroslav I'm not sure, perhaps javascript handles overflow of negatives differently and, combined with your while true loop, the infinite loop happens. Maybe someone with more JS knowledge can chime in. Your main problem however is the overflow I mentioned.

Comment: @IVlad, so I will wait for another answer. Are you okay with my doing this?

Comment: @Yaroslav of course! You should only accept the answer that fits your needs. Sorry I can't be of more help on the JS side.